# Trying to add Imageview to canvas via FrameLayout.addView();

Tags: android

I can add this logo to the canavas if I do this:

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(200,200);

ImageView boo = new ImageView(ExampletouchActivity.this);
boo.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
boo.setLayoutParams(lp);
fr.addView(boo); //this works fine
```

But if I try to add the same logo to the canvas like this it does not show anything up:

```
fr.addView(new Toucher(ExampletouchActivity.this));
```

My Toucher class is like so...

```
public class Toucher extends View{
ImageView boo;

public Toucher(Context context) 
{
    super(context);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(200,200);
    boo = new ImageView(context);
    boo.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    boo.setLayoutParams(lp);
}
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas c)
{   
    boo.draw(c);
}
```

I have been trying for ages and cannot work out why this imageview will not draw itself to the canvas?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Layout and Canvas aren't the same thing. Layout is "draw this for me", and Canvas is "I'm drawing this".  In your working example, you're taking a static image and putting it into a Layout.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the canvas, in a view things are different, so try using:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bg, src, dst, paint);
```